# Looking for the shared motif between several sequences

Tags: python, sequence, bioinformatics

I need to write a script which will loop over a list of sequences, find shared motifs between them (it is possible multiple solutions exist for different motifs) and print this motif which has been shared between all sequences.

In the below example

`chains = ['GATTACA', 'TAGACCA', 'ATACA']`

the `AT` is one of the shared motifs.  I'll be thankful for any solution of such task including usage of BioPython functions.

Recently I've made script which have loop the same set for the shorter sequence setting its as the reference and then try to find this ref sequence in each positions of the other chains. But I really don't know how to find shared motifs without defining the reference

```
# reference
xz=" ".join(chains)
ref= min(xz.split(), key=len)


# LOOKING FOR THE MOTIFS
for chain in chains:
    for i in range(len(chain)):
        if chain==ref:
            pass
        elif ref not in chain:
            print "%s has not been found in the  %s"%(ref, chain)
            break
        elif chain[i:].startswith(ref):
            print "%s has been detected in %s in the %d position" %(ref, chain, i+1)
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like Smith-Waterman?

Comment: Hi, the full question is listed here http://rosalind.info/problems/lcsm/

Answer (score 1):

It is only quick idea. You have to improve it, because it search almost all space. I hope it will help.

```
def cut_into_parts(chain, n):
    return [chain[x:x+n] for x in range(0, len(chain)-n)]

def cut_chains(chains, n):
    rlist = []
    for k,v in enumerate(chains):
        rlist.extend(cut_into_parts(chains, n))
    return rlist

def is_str_common(str, chains):
    for k,v in enumerate(chains):
        if !chains[k].contains(str):
            return false
    return true

def find_best_common(chains):
    clist = []
    for i in inverse(range(0, len(chains)))://inverse - I dont remmeber exactly the name of func
        clist.extend(cut_chains(chains, i))
    for k, v in enumerate(clist):
        return is_str_common(clist[k], chains)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach starts with the realization that the longest common substring can not be longer than the shortest string we're looking at. It should also be obvious that if we start with the longest possible candidate and only examine shorter candidates after eliminating longer ones, then we can stop as soon as we find a common substring.

So, we begin by sorting the DNA strings by length. We'll refer to the length of the shortest one as `l`.  Then the procedure is to test its substrings, beginning with the single substring of length `l`, and then the two substrings of length `l-1`, and so forth, until a match is found and we return it.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

def get_all_substrings(iterable):
    s = tuple(iterable)
    seen = set()
    for size in range(len(s)+1, 1, -1):
        for index in range(len(s)+1-size):
            substring = iterable[index:index+size]
            if substring not in seen:
                seen.add(substring)
                yield substring

def main(input_file, return_all=False):
    substrings = []
    records = list(SeqIO.parse(open(input_file),'fasta'))
    records = sorted(records, key=lambda record: len(str(record.seq)))
    first, rest = records[0], records[1:]
    rest_sequences = [str(record.seq) for record in rest]
    for substring in get_all_substrings(str(first.seq)):
        if all(substring in seq for seq in rest_sequences):
            if return_all:
                substrings.append(substring)
            else:
                return substring
    return substrings
```